# show only these products in search result whose category is active in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9, if user search "watch" in search box then only these product should show whose category is active.
Please suggest me how can i do this.
Thank you

Comment: anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override below class where magento fetch collection

```
Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result:_getProductCollection()
```

and use below collection to set filter by active category

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $this->_productCollection = $this->getListBlock()->getLoadedProductCollection();
    }
    $activeCategories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->getColumnValues('entity_id');

    $this->_productCollection->joinField(
        'category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
        'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left'
    )
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
            array('in' => $activeCategories),
    ));
    $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($this->_productCollection->getData());
    // die;
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```